# Python Beautiful Soup IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Every time I run the following function I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

I'm trying to find the price of the top result.

```
def parseFlight():
    r = requests.get(https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt=JFK.LAX.2020-06-11;c:USD;e:1;sc:b;sd:1;t:f;tt:o)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    x = soup.findAll('div')
    print(x)
    price = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'gws-flights-results__itinerary-price'})[0].find('div').text
    return price
```

Comment: Looks like there are no `div`s with the specified class on the page?

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve]. See [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: What should be inside my soup.find_all if I wanted to find the price from this website: https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt=JFK.LAX.2020-06-11;c:USD;e:1;sc:b;sd:1;t:f;tt:o